# how to get some data from one big array

Tags: javascript

I have a js file that has an array of people.

> data.js

```
const data = [
    [1, '', 'Fresno', 'name 1', 'name 2', 18, 'women'],
    [2, '', 'San Francisco', 'name 1', 'name 2', 20, 'man'],
    [3, '', 'Los Angeles', 'name 1', 'name 2', 22, 'women'],
    [4, '', 'Amador', 'name 1', 'name 2', 23, 'man'],
    [5, '', 'Kern', 'name 1', 'name 2', 33, 'women'],
    [6, '', 'Butte', 'name 1', 'name 2', 32, 'women'],
    [7, '', 'Santa Barbara', 'name 1', 'name 2', 21, 'man'],
];
```

In another file, I want to get data from an array and form my array with name, gender data.

I use the map, but I can't figure out how to implement it.

```
let newData = data.map(({name, gender}) => ({
    value: name,
    group: gender
}))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is an array so you will have to use its index.

```js
const data = [
    [1, '', 'Fresno', 'name 1', 'name 2', 18, 'women'],
    [2, '', 'San Francisco', 'name 1', 'name 2', 20, 'man'],
    [3, '', 'Los Angeles', 'name 1', 'name 2', 22, 'women'],
    [4, '', 'Amador', 'name 1', 'name 2', 23, 'man'],
    [5, '', 'Kern', 'name 1', 'name 2', 33, 'women'],
    [6, '', 'Butte', 'name 1', 'name 2', 32, 'women'],
    [7, '', 'Santa Barbara', 'name 1', 'name 2', 21, 'man'],
];

let newData = data.map((i) => ({
    value: i[3],
    group: i[6]
}))

console.log(newData);
```